# ¿Cómo mostrar meses de consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta para realizar gráficos:

```
SELECT precio*SUM(detalle_carrito.cantidad) AS venta, carrito.fecha AS 
fecha 
FROM detalle_carrito INNER JOIN carrito USING(id_carrito) WHERE 
carrito.fecha BETWEEN '2018/01/15' AND '2018/12/15' GROUP BY id_producto
```

(Las fechas son de ejemplo)

En el eje X del gráfico utilizo el `carrito.fecha` pero esto me muestra muchos resultados.

Lo que quiero saber es como separar las ventas por cada mes, de modo que saliera "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"... dependiendo del rango que se haya escrito.

Comment: Intenta agrupando no solo por id_producto, sino tambien por fecha.

Comment: @AlonsoUreña Soluciona un poco el problema (gracias) ya que no muestra cada registro de la tabla. Pero el problema es que si hay ventas cada dia y en las fechas se ingresa todo un año seguirian siendo demasiados resultados. Por eso deseo separarlos por meses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con MONTH obtienes el mes del 1 al 12.

```
SELECT precio*SUM(detalle_carrito.cantidad) AS venta, carrito.fecha AS 
    fecha, MONTH (carrito.fecha) AS mes
    FROM detalle_carrito 
    INNER JOIN carrito USING(id_carrito) 
    WHERE carrito.fecha BETWEEN '2018/01/15' AND '2018/12/15' 
    GROUP BY id_producto
```

También tienes MONTHNAME que te devuelve el nombre del mes en inglés. Con esto tienes la opción de agrupar por mes los resultados en caso de que quieras la suma por mes.

**Edición**

Para sumar todas las cantidades en función del mes, si el mes coincide suma. Obtendrás en una tupla la suma por mes, siendo cada mes una columna.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(MONTH (carrito.fecha) =1, precio*detalle_carrito.cantidad, 0)) AS enero,
    SUM(IF(MONTH (carrito.fecha) =2, precio*detalle_carrito.cantidad, 0)) AS febrero,
    -- añade igual el resto de los meses hasta completar el. Año

        FROM detalle_carrito 
        INNER JOIN carrito USING(id_carrito) 
        WHERE carrito.fecha BETWEEN '2018/01/15' AND '2018/12/15'
```

Comment: Primero gracias, pero aun me queda un pequeño problema: Con la forma en que lo hacia al principio me mostraba cada "venta" por compra de un producto, a manera de ejemplo digamos que el total de todas esas ventas en un mes especifico era $500. Cuando agrupo solo por mes obtengo $150 como total de mes.

Comment: He observado que se debe a que antes se evaluaba cada dia (en que hubiera un registro) del mes, mientras que ahora al agrupar por "mes" solo obtiene la suma del primer dia del mes en que se tenga un registro

Comment: Si te coge solo el primer registro de cada mes, para lo que quieres lo que agrupar por mes no va a funcionar, pero puedes asistir la suma a un condicional del mes, ahora te añado un ejemplo a ver si te sirve.

Comment: **Después de la edición** Mira se que esto debe ser un poco desesperante pero ahora el gestor me arroja el error `#1111 - Invalido uso de función en grupo`

Comment: Culpa mía, se me olvidó quitar el GROUP by al copiar, no es necesario

Comment: Sigue sucediendo. Yo hago esto desde phpMyAdmin, podria ser eso?

Comment: Soy yo que la estoy haciendo de memoria, perdón pero ahora mismo no tengo acceso a un gestor a mano. Quita el sum de dentro de if, creo que debe ser eso.

Comment: Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Estupendo, un placer :)

Answer (score 0):

Agrupa por mes además de id_producto. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
  precio*SUM(detalle_carrito.cantidad) AS venta, 
  month(fecha) as mes
FROM
  detalle_carrito INNER JOIN carrito USING(id_carrito)
WHERE 
  carrito.fecha BETWEEN '2018/01/15' AND '2018/12/15'
GROUP BY id_producto, month(fecha)
;
```